# Attack while using a VPN?

Tags: tls, vpn, attacks

While I was using a VPN, suddenly all websites refused to connect in HTTPS, and Firefox warned me since I enabled HTTPS-only mode. Is there a chance that this was an HTTPS downgrade attack? Should I treat my device as not safe to use right now?

Comment: Which VPN ? What error messages do you get ? Please describe your issue in more details. There is not enough information to advise you or even comprehend your problem.